# Как найти дополнительные диагонали в матрице?

Tags: python, алгоритм, списки

Надо найти все дополнителные (паралельные основной) диагонали в матрице, которые
идут с правой верхней стороны вниз налево. Основную такую диагональ нашел. При этом надо найти идущие строго подряд 4 и более элементов. Это тоже мне здесь сказали.

Вот код для основной и дополнительных диагоналей идущих сверху слева вниз направо:

```
    def finder(row,n):
       steck=[]
       for i in row:
          if not steck or steck==i:
             steck.append(i)
          else:
             if len(steck)>=n:
                break
             else:
                steck=[]
                steck.append(i)
       #print(len(steck)>=n)         
       return len(steck)>=n
    def horizontal(n,m):
       for row in m:
         if finder(row,n):
           return True
       return False
    def vertical(n,m):
       for col in zip(*m):
         if  finder(col,n):
            return True
       return False  
    def diagonal_dopoln_left(n,m):
       N=len(m)
       for counter in range(1,N):
          diag_len=N-counter
          list1=[m[i][i+counter] for i in range(diag_len)]
          print('list1',list1)
          list2=[m[i+counter][i] for i in range(diag_len)]
          print('list2',list2)      
          if finder(list1,n):
            return True
          if finder(list2,n):
            return True      
       return False 
    def diagonal_left(n,m):
       left_main_diag=[m[i][i] for i in range(len(m))]
       if finder(left_main_diag,n):
          return True 
       return False 
    def checkio(matrix):
      if diagonal_dopoln_left(4,matrix):
         return True
      return False




    if __name__ == '__main__':
       print(checkio([[11,12,14,17],
                      [14,15,16,10],
                      [10,18,12,11],
                      [10,81,12,11]
                ]))
       #Ответ:
       #list1 [14, 10]
       #list2 [10, 81]
       #list1 [17]
       #list2 [10]
       #False
```

Нашел дополнительные диагонали идущие сверху от основной которая идет справа сверху вниз таким кодом:

```
def finder(row,n):
    steck=[]
    for i in row:
        if not steck or steck==i:
            steck.append(i)
        else:
            if len(steck)>=n:
                break
            else:
                steck=[]
                steck.append(i)
    #print(len(steck)>=n)         
    return len(steck)>=n

def diagonal_right(n,m):
    left_main_diag=[m[i][-(i+1)] for i in range(len(m))]
    print('left_main_diag:',left_main_diag)
    if finder(left_main_diag,n):
        return True 
    return False 

def diagonal_dopoln_right(n,m):
    N=len(m)
    for counter in range(1,N):
        diag_len=N-counter
        list1=[m[i][-(i+counter)] for i in range(diag_len+1)]
        print('list1',list1)
        #list2=[m[i][-(i+1)] for i in range(diag_len+1)]
        #print('list2',list2)      
        #if finder(list1,n):
            #return True
        #if finder(list2,n):
            #return True      
    return False 


def checkio(matrix):
    n=4
    if diagonal_dopoln_right(n,matrix):
        return True
    return False

if __name__ == '__main__':
   print(checkio([[11,12,14,17],
                  [14,15,16,10],
                  [10,18,12,11],
                  [10,81,12,11]                               
                     ]))
   #Ответ:
   #list1 [17, 16, 18, 10]
   #list1 [14, 15, 10]
   #list1 [12, 14]
   #False
```

Как найти такие диагонали снизу от основной, надо как-то правильно расставить индексы, пробовал по разному-return -1 )

Comment: `При этом надо найти идущие строго подряд 4 и более элементов.` - можете пояснить, что это значит?  В диагонали среди элементов должны быть 4 или более последовательных числа?

Comment: Да, в диагонали должны быть строго подряд идущие равные элементы(числа),у меня в коде это обеспечивает функция finder(),но мне нужно нижние диагонали  от "правой основной" в списковую компановку list2 выделить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пусть есть произвольная матрица `n x n`. Рассмотрим, чему равны суммы индексов на диагоналях, идущих из левого нижнего угла в правый верхний (иначе говоря, на побочных диагоналях). На рисунке у меня `n == 3`, в клетках записаны суммы индексов элемента. 
[image: matrix]

Можно увидеть, что для элементов, находящихся на самой длинной побочной диагонали сумма индексов равна `n-1`; номера строк при этом (в которых встречаются элементы из этой диагонали) идут в диапазоне `[0, n-1]`. Для тех побочных диагоналей, что стоят выше неё, сумма индексов меньше: для соседней - меньше на единицу, для следующей - на двойку и т.д. `(сумма = n-1 - distance)`; номера строк, содержащих элементы этой диагонили, пробегают значения `[0, n-1-distance]` (`distance` - расстояние от самой длинной побочной диагонали до рассматривоемой, причём расстояние между соседними диагоналями понимается равным единице). Для диагоналей снизу от самой длинной сумма индексов наоборот возрастает `(сумма = n-1 + distance)`, а номера строк, в которых стоят элементы из этих диагоналей, меняются как `[distance, n-1]`. Теперь можно легко написать функцию, которая найдёт все побочные диагонали, пробегаясь по строкам, в которых есть элементы для данной диагонали, получая номер столбца из номера строки:

```
def checkio_2(matrix):
    n = len(matrix)    # размер квадратной матрицы
    all_diags = []     # здесь будут храниться все найденные
                       #     побочные диагонали
    for distance in range(1, n):    # distance - расстояние от главной диагонали
        sum_tl = n - 1 - distance    # сумма индексов (верхний-левый угол)
        sum_br = n - 1 + distance    # сумма индексов (нижний-правый угол)
        all_diags.extend([
            [matrix[i][sum_tl - i] for i in range(n - distance)], # верх-лев диаг
            [matrix[i][sum_br - i] for i in range(distance, n)]   # ниж-прав диаг
        ])
    return all_diags    # возвращаем все побочные диагонали
```

Теперь встаёт вопрос фильтрации полученных значений. Насколько я могу судить, Ваша функция `finder` плоховато для этого подходит:

```
def finder(row,n):
    steck=[]
    for i in row:
        if not steck or steck==i:    # steck==i - сравнивать список и число
                                     #     вряд ли хорошая идея;
                                     #     к тому же, на нулевой итерации
                                     #     попадём сюда, т.к. not steck == True
            steck.append(i)          # теперь steck == [i, ]
        else:                        # на второй итерации идём сюда
            if len(steck)>=n:        # len(steck) == 1
                break
            else:                    # поэтому
                steck=[]             # опустошаем steck
                steck.append(i)      # теперь steck == [i, ] снова
                                     # и ходим по этой ветке
    return len(steck)>=n             # вернём False, ведь len(steck) == 1
```

То есть, независимо от того, что в найденных диагоналях, возвращается `False`. Я бы предложил сделать иначе (для произвольного `n`, где `n` - нужная длина последовательности идущих подряд возрастающих или убывающих элементов). Если нужно, чтоб поиск происходил лишь среди последовательных элементов диагонали, можно написать так:

```
def finder_2(row, n=4):
    for idx in range(len(row)-(n-1)):
        n_increasing = 0    # столько раз следующий элемент больше предыдущего
        n_decreasing = 0    # а столько раз - наоборот
        for i in range(idx, idx+n-1):
            if row[i+1] - row[i] == 1:    # возрастание
                n_increasing += 1
            elif row[i] - row[i+1] == 1:  # убывание
                n_decreasing += 1
        if n-1 in [n_increasing, n_decreasing]: # если все возрастают
                                                # или все убывают
            return True
    return False    # если не найдено строго монотонной 
                    # последовательности нужной длины
```

Таким образом, можно проверить с помощью `finder_2` все найденные в `checkio_2` диагонали. Если нужно проверить, есть среди элементов диагонали четыре (или произвольное `n`) число последовательных чисел, не обязательно встречающихся в самой диагонали подряд, нужно в `finder_2` передавать отсортированную диагональ.